# Passing arrays from GAS script to html file, Global J.S. variables

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have the following google apps script that populates an array based on values of a google-sheet as well as creates a web-app. The top section of my code has been tested and works fine.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FormFile')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function ChannelList() {

var InfoSheetIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName("InfoSheets");
var InfoSheetFile = InfoSheetIterator.next();
var InfoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(InfoSheetFile);

var NumChannels = getLastRow('A');
var ChannelTwoDimArray = InfoSheet.getRange('A2:A'+String(NumChannels)).getValues();

return ChannelTwoDimArray;
}
```

Then I am in the process of trying to declare an array as a global variable in Javascript and then use that array for other purposes further down the road with this code. I am getting an empty array and I am not sure why. Any tips appreciated.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<button type="button" onclick="tester()">Click Me!</button>
<p id = "tester"></p>
    <script>
    //declaring global variables
    window.onload = populateArrays;

    function getChannelList(value) {
    window.ChannelList = value;
    }




    function populateArrays() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getChannelList).ChannelList();

    }

    function tester() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.ChannelList[0][0];
    }

   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Things I have tried:
- Adding multiple script tags.
- setting a timeout to the printing of ChannelList values.
- global variables
- local storage window variables

I am missing something here. When I print the values of ChannelList in the getChannelList() method it works fine, but when I try to access its values outside of that scope... no such luck.

Comment: I know of at least a few of options.  You can put the data into the browsers window object, which persists for the session.  `window.ChannelList = value;`  You could store the content in a hidden HTML tag.  You could save the content to the browsers local storage.  [Link to info - Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: @SandyGood tried all but the hidden html tag method and so far no luck. Is there a standard way to pass values from apps script functions to javascript global variables for web apps.

Comment: Have you checked for a value coming back, and being received by the `getChannelList(value)` function?  `console.log('value: ' + value)`  What is the value being returned when it gets to the browser?

Comment: @SandyGood Yes I checked that and it is printing the right values which is why I am so confused. The value is an array of strings. Although the typeof(value) is giving object not array but rather object.

Comment: If you use `window.ChannelList = value;`, you can immediately try to get the value out as a test.  `console.log('value: ' + window.ChannelList);` If that works, then the problem is with some other code that you are not showing.  You aren't showing any code to get the stored value.

Comment: @SandyGood Edited. I think I might need to add a timer to get the requested info because the console.log(window.ChannelList[0][0]) is printing before the window.ChannelList assignment is made.

Comment: Are you running multiple simultaneous calls to `google.script.run.myFunctionName()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114960/discussion-between-james-dickens-and-sandy-good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `window.onload` event and a success handler

```
<script>
  window.getChannelList = function(rtrnValue) {//Runs AFTER the server function completes
    //ToDo - Process the return value
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(getChannelList)//define the function to run on completion
      .ChannelList();//Call the server function

    console.log(window.ChannelList[0][0]);

  };


</script>
```

Comment: Same problem unfortunately

Comment: You can't get the returned value inside of the calling function, or right after the call.  You'll need to get the returned value, and continue processing from the success handler function.

Comment: Ok. Should have thought of that.